# How can I checkout a specified number of levels in svn 1.6

Tags: svn

I have a very large SVN repository and I want to check out a depth of 6 levels from the URL that I pass to the checkout command. I've read up on the -depth parameter but it seems very 'powerful' but not very useful. I *could* spend over a day checking out individual folders and specifying a depth parameter but 6 levels is good enough for me to be immediately productive.

Can anyone tell me how I can achieve this with the svn 1.6 client please?

My folder structure is:-

```
adapters/
  |---esb--
  |       |
  |       proj1 (with branches/trunk underneath)
  |       |
  |       ...
  |       |
  |       projn (with branches/trunk underneath)
  |---ejb--
  |       |
  |       proj1 (with branches/trunk underneath)
  |       |
  |       ...
  |       |
  |       projn (with branches/trunk underneath)
```

I have about 15 of the 'adapters' folder structure above each of which has 1..n number of projects which come and go.

Basically it looks like I need to write a script which updates adapters/esb and adapters/esb with 'immediates' then loop through each child (proj1 etc) with immediates (to get branches/trunk folders only) , then update with immediates on those children to finally get the pom.xmls.

This is all possible with a Groovy script but how hard would it be to just give me a parameter to checkout a specific depth.

Yes, it's powerful, no it's not helpful.

If anyone has spotted anything I've missed I'm desperate to recant ! :-)

|

Comment: Show your tree, dude!!!

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my question with the tree and more information

Answer (score 0):

1. Re-read [topic "Sparse Directories"](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn.advanced.sparsedirs.html) in SVN Book **carefully** and **understand it** fully, with special attention starting from sentence

> Here's an example of how we might build out a portion of one branch of our family's tree, enable full recursion on another branch, and keep still other pieces pruned

2. Define checkout-plan for your tree (get folder-tree with `svn ls -R | grep /$`)
3. Write bat-file for all needed `svn up --set-depth ...` (it can be better with `immediates` or `exclude` under some conditions - your job to detect which to use) - depending on the situation it can be *minutes or tens of minutes*, **not day** (if brain used for planning)